# How to push a message onto azure service bus within a function

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I need my azure function written in C# to push a message onto the service bus.  The examples I've seen online show how an azure function can be triggered when a new message happens.

Is there an example available?

**Current azure function (C#)**

```
[FunctionName("IHandleMessage")]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("my.topic", "my.subscription", Connection = "mybus_SERVICEBUS")]string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
        {

            // send new message?

        }
```

Many thanks!
J

**Update**

How to create a new message within an azure function

```
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("my.topic", "my.subscription", Connection = "mybus_SERVICEBUS")]string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
        {            
            ServiceBusOutput("hello", log);  // Create a new message
        }

        [FunctionName("AnotherEvent")]
        [return: ServiceBus("my.other.queue", Connection = "mySERVICEBUS")]
        public static string ServiceBusOutput([HttpTrigger] dynamic input, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# function processed: {input.Text}");
            return input.Text;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look for [output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#output) examples.

> The following example shows a C# function that sends a Service Bus queue message:
>
> ```
> [FunctionName("ServiceBusOutput")]
> [return: ServiceBus("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
> public static string ServiceBusOutput([HttpTrigger] dynamic input, ILogger log)
> {
>     log.LogInformation($"C# function processed: {input.Text}");
>     return input.Text;
> }
> ```
>
> Here's C# script code that creates multiple messages:
>
> ```
> public static async Task Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log, IAsyncCollector<string> outputSbQueue)
> {
>     string message = $"Service Bus queue messages created at: {DateTime.Now}";
>     log.LogInformation(message); 
>     await outputSbQueue.AddAsync("1 " + message);
>     await outputSbQueue.AddAsync("2 " + message);
> }
> ```

Comment: Is it possible to send to a different topic?

Comment: Yes, you can use `EntityType = EntityType.Topic` within the ServiceBus attribute

Comment: And I want to trigger this new message within my ServiceBusTrigger function.  Not sure how with this example

Comment: Apology up-front for this comment that might irritate @Jack. Alex has provided an answer and you keep adding questions w/o marking his answer. Perhaps you should do that first and then solicit for more information? After all, he did answer your questions. Thank you.